# Retrieve data from multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

There are three dictionaries:
trucks_dic, items_dic and loaded_trucks

How can I replace the truck keys and values from keys and values of Trucks and Items Dictionaries ?

```
truck_dic = {6: [21.0, 7.0, 7.0],
             7: [23.0, 7.0, 7.0],
             8: [27.0, 7.0, 7.0],
             9: [20.0, 7.0, 7.0],
            10: [24.0, 7.0, 7.0],
            11: [28.0, 8.0, 8.0],
            12: [32.0, 8.0, 8.0],
            13: [32.0, 9.0, 10.0],
            14: [32.0, 9.0, 10.0],
            15: [20.0, 8.0, 8.0],
            16: [20.0, 8.0, 8.0]}

Items_dic = {0: [4.6, 4.3, 4.3],
 1: [4.6, 4.3, 4.3],
 2: [6.0, 5.6, 9.0],
 3: [8.75, 5.6, 6.6],
 4: [6.0, 5.16, 6.6],
 5: [6.0, 5.6, 9.0],
 6: [8.75, 5.6, 6.6],
 7: [4.6, 4.3, 4.3],
 8: [6.0, 5.6, 9.0],
 9: [8.75, 5.6, 6.6],
 10: [6.0, 5.16, 6.6]}

loaded_trucks = {'23.0x7.0x7.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30, 4.60x4.30x4.30, 
                                  6.60x6.00x5.16, 6.60x6.00x5.16'],
                 '27.0x7.0x7.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30, 9.00x6.00x5.60, 
                                   8.75x6.60x5.60'],
                 '20.0x8.0x8.0': ['9.00x6.00x5.60, 8.75x6.60x5.60'],
                 '21.0x7.0x7.0': ['9.00x6.00x5.60, 8.75x6.60x5.60']}
```

Such that it gives

```
loaded_trucks = {'7': ['0', '7', '4', '10'],
                 '8': ['1', '5', '9'],
                 '16': ['2', '3'],
                 '6': ['6', '8']}
```

PS: The Dimensions in loaded_trucks are jumbled

Comment: Could you please shorten this code to a Minimal and easy to look, understand and solve the problem?

Comment: Can you please explain *how* the expected output is derived from the input? In how far is the initial ``'23.0x7.0x7.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30, 4.60x4.30x4.30, 6.60x6.00x5.16, 6.60x6.00x5.16']`` related to the final ``'7': ['0', '4', '7', '10']``, for example? Do you evaluate the expressions in the first ``loaded_trucks``? How are duplicates values (e.g. for 0, 1 and 7) in ``Items_dic`` resolved for matching?

Comment: The `loaded_trucks` dictionary previously had `4.60x4.30x4.30` in the first value list which is replaced by `0` as `Items_dic[0] = [4.6, 4.3, 4.3]` but also `Items_dic[1] = [4.6, 4.3, 4.3]` where as in the second value list its replaced by `1`. Any clarification about this?

Comment: So there's this library pyshipping which I am using and it takes the input in "AxBxC" format and provide output in the same.

Comment: @pistol2myhead There are multiple items of same dimensions and the library is filling them out in trucks(Best Fit). Even I am unsure about this that how to differentiate between the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
truck_dic = {6: [21.0, 7.0, 7.0],
             7: [23.0, 7.0, 7.0],
             8: [27.0, 7.0, 7.0],
             9: [20.0, 7.0, 7.0],
            10: [24.0, 7.0, 7.0],
            11: [28.0, 8.0, 8.0],
            12: [32.0, 8.0, 8.0],
            13: [32.0, 9.0, 10.0],
            14: [32.0, 9.0, 10.0],
            15: [20.0, 8.0, 8.0],
            16: [20.0, 8.0, 8.0]}

Items_dic = {0: [4.6, 4.3, 4.3],
 1: [4.6, 4.3, 4.3],
 2: [6.0, 5.6, 9.0],
 3: [8.75, 5.6, 6.6],
 4: [6.0, 5.16, 6.6],
 5: [6.0, 5.6, 9.0],
 6: [8.75, 5.6, 6.6],
 7: [4.6, 4.3, 4.3],
 8: [6.0, 5.6, 9.0],
 9: [8.75, 5.6, 6.6],
 10: [6.0, 5.16, 6.6]}

loaded_trucks = {'23.0x7.0x7.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30, 4.60x4.30x4.30, 6.60x6.00x5.16, 6.60x6.00x5.16'],
                 '27.0x7.0x7.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30, 9.00x6.00x5.60, 8.75x6.60x5.60'],
                 '20.0x8.0x8.0': ['9.00x6.00x5.60, 8.75x6.60x5.60'],
                 '21.0x7.0x7.0': ['9.00x6.00x5.60, 8.75x6.60x5.60']}

# Build dimensions to truck and item mappings
truck_dict = {tuple(sorted(v)): str(k) for k, v in truck_dic.items()}

items_dict = dict()
for k, v in Items_dic.items():
    items_dict.setdefault(tuple(sorted(v)), []).append(str(k))

# Generate result
result = dict()
def standardize(s):
    return tuple(sorted(float(v) for v in s.split('x')))

for k, v in loaded_trucks.items():
    # Note that the values in loaded_trucks are lists of a ONE str
    # and not a list of strs of dimensions.
    items = v[0].split(',')
    items = [i.strip() for i in items]

    print(items)
    print([standardize(i) for i in items])
    k = standardize(k)
    result[truck_dict[k]] = [items_dict[standardize(i)].pop() for i in items]
```

The output, `result` is

```
{'7': ['7', '1', '10', '4'],
 '8': ['0', '8', '9'],
 '16': ['5', '6'],
 '6': ['2', '3']}
```

Note that the items with the same dimensions are interchangeable. For e.g., item 5 and 8 have the same dimensions, so they can be swapped.

Also, we do not care if the order of individual dimensions are re-ordered because this would just mean the item is rotated. For e.g., an item with dimensions "4.60x4.30x4.30" is considered the same as another item with dimensions "4.30x4.30x4.60".

Lastly, each item is only assigned once, but we assume the items in the original `loaded_trucks` dictionary are all accounted for in `Items_dic` so there will be no shortage or left-over else popping from the list will produce an error.

Comment: Brilliantly answered, but actually the items cannot be swapped because while they have same dimensions, they could have different weights.

Comment: @RahulSharma Ok... then how would you distinguish them if the weights are not given? You will need to be more specific. One possibility is to append the weight to the end of the tuple representing each item, but you will have to give the weights.

Comment: Okay one approach I can think of is this but IDK if it's implementable or not

Comment: we have the original dictionary 

packed_items = {'7': ['0', '4', '7', '10', '11'],
 '8': ['1', '5', '9', '12'],
 '16': ['2', '3'],
 '6': ['6', '8']}

we can convert this dictionary to AxBXC format and compare which elements are there and which have been removed by pyshipping library, Can we?
and then reconvert them by comparing!

Comment: When asking questions here, it helps if you can provide a minimal self-contained problem as we do not have access to your code or your domain knowledge. For e.g., neither me nor most people here knows how the pyshipping library works. But it seems like you have figured out how to extend the current solution. Good luck :).